# py2app pyqt missing a library, app doesn't start on mac os x

Tags: macos, qt, pyqt, py2app

When I try to launch on a mac where no developer tools and QT/PyQt is installed my app doesn't start. Console says that there is a library missing which is referenced from QtHelp. It's the libQtCLucene.4.dylib. I've uploaded a screenshot: [dcs.co.at/pics/py2app_librarymissing.jpg](http://dcs.co.at/pics/py2app_librarymissing.jpg)

my setup file looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['/Users/k-effects/clipfinder.py']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': ['sip', 'PyQt4', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.QtGui'], 'excludes': ['PyQt4.QtDesigner', 'PyQt4.QtNetwork', 'PyQt4.QtOpenGL', 'PyQt4.QtScript', 'PyQt4.QtSql', 'PyQt4.QtTest', 'PyQt4.QtWebKit', 'PyQt4.QtXml', 'PyQt4.phonon']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

But still all the excluded Frameworks are included in the final bundle and increasing the
size of the package. But first problem is still, that it doesn't open without this library...
THX for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using a link now it runs:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libQtCLucene.4.8.5.dylib /usr/lib/libQtCLucene.4.dylib
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Can you explain what you did in more detail. For example, where do you put the above ln -s ... code?

Comment: I wrote a small installer script which does the linking. So the user had only to doulbe click the installer script. I saw on the osx console what the problem was and linking it did the job.